# Google Calendar Event is Off By One Day When I Create with App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am using Google App Script to create a calendar event. I'm taking a calendar data type in a google sheet and using that as an input for the input (one for start date and one for end date) to the calendar api. After I send it to Google Calendar it shows up one day before the the days that I specified.

Example: if I input January 18 to January 19 it will show in the Calendar as January 17 to January 18.

I can manually correct it but it's hacky.

```
startDate = '1/18/2019';
endDate = '1/19/2019';

CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID).createAllDayEvent(title,startDate, endDate);
```

Comment: Maybe the days start at 0 ?

Comment: If you're grabbing dates from a google sheet it may be caused by the timezone setting on the spreadsheet itself. Calendar is pretty particular about the way it likes dates formatted. Could you provide more of your code, I'm particularly interested your `getValues()` for the dates.

Comment: @ross, I was just trying to simplify, the value of getValues was the startDate and endDate variable and it was the date cell type. I'm in Chicago and it's set to Central time. If that's not enough let me know and I can clone the project and send a link. Thanks!

Comment: Try wrapping your `getValues()` into a `new Date()` for example: `new Date(startDate)` and see how that behaves. If that doesn't work you could try formatting it with your local timezone using `Utilities.formatDate`, documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)).